# UnboundLocalError "local variable result referenced before assignment" with variable even though i assigned it

Tags: python, local, unbound

I am making a custom programming language. This is a method in a class in my code. When i need to return the result, the error occurs.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

```
   def visit_BinOpNode(self, node):
        left = self.visit(node.left_node)
        right = self.visit(node.right_node)

        if node.op_tok.value == TT_PLUS:
            result = left.add_to(right)
        elif node.op_tok.value == TT_MINUS:
            result = left.sub_to(right)
        elif node.op_tok.value == TT_MUL:
            result = left.mul_to(right)
        elif node.op_tok.value == TT_DIV:
            result = left.div_to(right)

        return result.set_pos(node.pos_start, node.pos_end)
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` is not defined if none of the if statements evaluates to true, so it will error out in the last line when you try to use `result`. You can set a default value like `result = None` or something and check for that at the end, or you could use `else` instead of `else if` for the last branch.